# Jade error putting variable as label

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I got an error of jade **input is self closing and should not have content**.

```
input(type='radio') This discount has
   -if type == 1
    | #{value} %
   -else
    | RM #{value}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant put content insade input. This html is invalid

```
<input type="radio">This discount has 0</input>
```

Probably you want

```
label
    input(type='radio') 
    | This discount has
    - if (type == 1)
      | #{value} %
    - else
      | RM #{value}
```

Or

```
input(type='radio') 
span This discount has
- if (type == 1)
  | #{value} %
- else
  | RM #{value}
```

Comment: unexpected token "indent"?

Comment: remove spaces before the tag